# when servlet receive xml data , there is a error

Tags: java, xml, dom, servlets

servelt code

```
System.out.println(" ================servlet==================");
InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
int a = in.available();
byte[] b = new byte[a];
in.read(b);
String stringValue = new String(b,"utf-8");
System.out.println("receive data==="+stringValue);
OutputStream dataOut = response.getOutputStream();
String responseData = "<test>test</test>";
System.out.println("response datea==="+responseData);
dataOut.write(responseData.getBytes("utf-8"));
dataOut.flush();
dataOut.close();
```

client code

```
System.out.println("================client======================");
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("test address");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
String sendData = "<data>send</data>";
System.out.println("send data="+sendData);
OutputStream dataOut = con.getOutputStream();
dataOut.write(sendData.getBytes("utf-8"));
dataOut.flush();
dataOut.close();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
int a = in.available();
byte[] b = new byte[a];
in.read(b);
String stringValue = new String(b,"utf-8");
in.close();
System.out.println("receive data="+stringValue);
```

I get the print results
servlet console
    ================servlet==================
    receive data===
    response datea===test

client console

```
================client======================
send data=<data>send</data>
receive data=<test>test</test>
```

My question is that servlet can't receive the data from the client

who can help me?

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: Then what is the reason you posted it here.Dealing with people in right manner matters !!!

Comment: but i can get the data from request.getParamenter("")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is that servlet can't receive the data from the client

It may not be the *only* problem, but this code is completely broken:

```
int a = in.available();
byte[] b = new byte[a];
in.read(b);
```

You're assuming that *all* the data is available right at the start. You should instead be reading from the stream until it runs out of data. Given that you want the result as text, I'd wrap the stream in an `InputStreamReader` and read from there. For example:

```
BufferdReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Servlet read line: " + line);
}
```

If you *actually* want to read it as XML, you should be able to pass the `InputStream` (or `Reader`) to an XML parser library to create a DOM.

You should be doing the same thing in the client code too, by the way. Basically:

- Never ignore the return value of `InputStream.read`
- Avoid using `available()`; it's rarely appropriate
- Use an `InputStreamReader` to read text from a stream, rather than constructing it yourself from the bytes
- Use an XML API to read XML rather than handling it as raw text

Comment: If I do this
Document document = null;
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader ();
  document = reader.read (new InputStreamReader (conn.getInputStream (), "UTF-8"));

I get the exception

org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line -1 of document  : Premature end of file. Nested exception: Premature end of file.  

thanks

Comment: @fenger: That suggests the data isn't actually getting to the servlet then. Why are you using `DataOutputStream` in the client? It seems pointless to me. I suggest you use Wireshark to diagnose what's happening at a network level.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I can see that the value of `int b` is `0` so it is not reading any data from the input stream.

According to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29)

```
available
```

will always return `0` for InputStream which has been extended byt the 
`ServletInputStream`.
As told by Jon or
**Edit:**

```
InputStream is=request.getInputStream();
OutputStream os=response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int chunk = is.read(buf);
```

Comment: so how can I get the data?